# Is there a way to get back to the top level page from any given page in tabris?

Tags: java, android, ios, tabris

Is there any other way than the openpage() method? Also I guess I found a bug with that way. When I do it with openpage() I get back to the top level page but the back button on the upperleft(IOS) is shown which should not be there on a top level page - havent tried it on android yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openPage is the quickest way. An alternative can be to close all other open pages.

The bug sounds strange. Can you open an issue here: https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris/issues